# slow application startup in flutter Getx

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, flutter-getx

I have application that I have been made it by get x state management   and I added general binding class to inject all necessary  classes in my project ( repository/remote data datasource/local data source/auth controller/dio/language controller )

and this is my classes:

**http helper**(remote data source)

```
 class HttpHelper implements IHttpHelper {
  final Dio _dio = Get.find(tag: CARAM_API);
  final Dio _dioGoogle = Get.find(tag: GOOGLE_API);
  final PrefsHelper _prefsHelper = Get.find();

  }
```

**prefs helper**(local data source)

```
class PrefsHelper  {


  Future<SharedPreferences> getPrefs() async{
    return await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }}
```

**repository**

```
class Repository {
  final HttpHelper  _httpHelper=Get.find();
  final PrefsHelper _prefsHelper=Get.find();
 // final IDbHelper _iDbHelper;
  Repository();

}
```

**this is my MainBinding**

```
class MainBinding implements Bindings{
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut(() => AuthController(),);
    Get.lazyPut(()=>((Dio(BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: BaseUrl,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          "charset": "utf-8",
          "Accept-Charset": "utf-8"
        },
        responseType: ResponseType.plain)))),tag:API );



    Get.lazyPut(()=>((Dio(BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: BaseUrlGoogle,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          "charset": "utf-8",
          "Accept-Charset": "utf-8"
        },
        responseType: ResponseType.plain)))),tag:GOOGLE_API );


    Get.lazyPut(() => PrefsHelper(),);
    Get.lazyPut(() => HttpHelper());
    Get.lazyPut(() => Repository());
    Get.lazyPut(() => SplashController());
    }
```

and finally this is my main

```
return GetMaterialApp(
          title: 'my app ',
          locale: AppLanguageKeys.appLang.value == AR
              ? const Locale('ar', '')
              : const Locale('en', ''),
          translations: Translation(),
          initialBinding: MainBinding(),
          theme:
          ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white),
        
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          initialRoute: SplashScreen.routeName,
         
        );
```

**when I start the app it took so much time to show the first page I think the problem in my binding class what should I do in this case**